# Together at least X times SQL

Tags: sql, database, db2

[SQL] Lets say I have a table with persons and places like this

```
NAME - PLACE
John | Park
John | Restaurant
John | Market
Bob  | Park
Bob  | Restaurant
Bob  | Market
Bob  | Pub
Bob  | Work
Tom  | Park
Tom  | Cinema
Ray  | Work
Ray  | Pub
```

and I want to know which persons were together in pair on the same places at least X times, so expected output would be:

```
for X = 1:
John
Bob
Tom
Ray
```

Because:
John and Bob were together in Park, Restaurant and Market
Bob and Ray were together in Work and Pub
Tom and John were together in Park

```
for X = 2:
John
Bob
Ray
```

Because:
John and Bob were together in Park, Restaurant and Market
Bob and Ray were together in Work and Pub

```
for X = 3:
John
Bob
```

Because:
John and Bob were together in Park, Restaurant and Market

I do not care about pairs, I just want to add person to the result table if he was on same place together with another person. The reason is to find out which persons stick together the most.

Preferably using SQL if it is possible.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For X=N (after `>=`):

```
with t(NAME, PLACE) as (values
  ('John', 'Park')
, ('John', 'Restaurant')
, ('John', 'Market')
, ('Bob', 'Park')
, ('Bob', 'Restaurant')
, ('Bob', 'Market')
, ('Bob', 'Pub')
, ('Bob', 'Work')
, ('Tom', 'Park')
, ('Tom', 'Cinema')
, ('Ray', 'Work')
, ('Ray', 'Pub')
)
select distinct a.name
from t a
where exists (
select 1
from t b
where b.NAME<>a.NAME
and (select count(1) from t ta join t tb on ta.place=tb.place and ta.name=a.name and tb.name=b.name)>=N
);
```

Comment: It you replace N with 3, then it returns the desired result.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with multiple joins.  For X = 1, then:

```
select p.place, t11.person, t21.person
from (select distinct place as place1
      from t
     ) p join
     t t1
     on t1.place = p.place join
     t t2
     on t2.place = p.place and
        t2.person not in (t1.person);
```

For X = 2:

```
select p.place1, p.place2, t1.person, t2.person
from (select distinct t1.place as place1, t2.place as place2
      from t t1 join
           t t2
           on t1.place < t2.place
     ) p join
     t t11
     on t11.place = p.place1 join
     t t21
     on t21.place = p.place1 and
        t21.person not in (t11.person) join
     t t12
     on t12.place = p.place2 and
        t12.person = t11.person join
     t t22
     on t22.place = p.place2 and
        t22.person = t21.person;
```

Adding additional places follows this method, with two joins for each new place.

[Here](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/2GthwB4bjxRnjfwFEPzNT6/0) is a db<>fiddle.

Comment: Thanks for superfast answer, but when I try this solution, I got error unknown column t1.person.. Scoping probably? [link](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/2GthwB4bjxRnjfwFEPzNT6/0)